# R ggplot2 aesthetics: Color, point shape, and point filled/unfilled based on 3 separate variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a graph of tree seed width over the past few decades from data that was collected from 6 different sites. I want the graph to have several features depending on different conditions in my dataset:

1. Color represents the site at which the data was collected
2. Point shape represents the type of data (in my case this is data collected either from a sitewide survey or from individual trees)
3. Point fill/unfilled represents whether there were over/under 20 samples weighed from a particular site within a given year.

I've managed to get the first two down fine, producing the following graph:

[image: average seed width over the years]

I'm now struggling to figure out the last part. I think it may be just to add a column to my dataset with the numbers that correspond to the shape I want to be plotted depending on two variables (data type and sample count) and then use that column in the geom_point shape argument, but I am unsure how to go about that.

I've previously done a graph where I didn't need to specify the data type so I used an ifelse statement to create a new column with the numbers corresponding to the shape I want depending on whether there are over/under 20 seeds, but I don't know how to do this with the 4 possible combinations I could have in this situation. It looked something like this:
EDIT: I've actually just realized the below code does not work...

```
# if length >20 make it a circle (1 in ggplot2 shape arg), if <20 make it a cross (4 in ggplot 2 shape arg)

phys_MLW$pt_shape <- ifelse(phys_MLW$no_seeds > 20, '1', '4')
```

I then used this new column in my geom_point shape aesthetic which worked. So I guess something along these lines would work for my current problem?

Here's my code at the minute, which produces the graph in the image above:

```
# yearly variation in width
    
ggplot(phys_MLW, aes(x = year, y = avg_width, color = site)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = data_collection), size = 2.5) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(phys_MLW$year),
                     max(phys_MLW$year), by = 2))) + 
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Average Width", col = "Site") + 
  scale_shape(name = "Source of samples", labels = c("Individual trees", "Sitewide"))
```

EDIT: Here is a (hopefully) copy/pastable example of the data I'm using:

> site  year    avg_width   no_seeds    data_collection
> NETTLEBED 2007    6.7925  36  indiv_phys
> NETTLEBED 2009    6.825555556 30  site_phys
> BENWELL   2007    8.14    30  site_phys
> BENWELL   2019    8.039333333 50  indiv_phys
> FISH HILL 2007    7.241975309 32  indiv_phys
> FISH HILL 2009    6.7 8   site_phys
> SPENNYMOOR    2007    7.260606061 11  site_phys
> SPENNYMOOR    2019    7.057037037 38  indiv_phys
> PATCHAM PLACE 2007    6.920952381 29  indiv_phys
> PATCHAM PLACE 2009    6.99    30  site_phys
> RIPON 2007    6.635416667 16  site_phys
> RIPON 2008    6.35037037  10  indiv_phys

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include an example of your data in copy-pastable format, which you can obtain with `dput(head(phys_MLW))`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using point size to represent the number of seeds?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(site = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
                  year = rep(2011:2014, times = 3),
                  avg_width = runif(n = 12, min = 6, max = 8),
                  no_seeds = sample(3:30, size = 12, replace = TRUE),
                  data_collection = sample(c("indiv", "site"), size = 12, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = avg_width, color = site, size = no_seeds)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = data_collection)) + 
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 10), breaks = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25))
```

[image: Bubble plot example]

If the precise threshold of 20 seeds is important, this might not be the best way to present it though, because the size of other shapes than a circle can be difficult to see.

More bubble plot options here: https://r-graph-gallery.com/320-the-basis-of-bubble-plot.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but not recommended in the ggplot style as not all the shapes are fillable. If you still want to do it then you have to manually specify the shapes manually first, to ensure that they are fillable. I hope the example below clarifies what I mean. But be aware that the legend won't display correctly. I can't find a way to fix that.

Another option is to use some other aesthetic to signify that variable. Perhaps using asterisk as you suggested.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg,y = hp,
             color = factor(cyl),
             shape = ifelse(disp > 300,TRUE,FALSE),
             label = ifelse(wt > 2.6,"*",""))) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(nudge_y = +20) + 
  labs(shape = "Disp > 300",
       caption = "* indicates wt > 2.6",
       color = "Cyl") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","pink")) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty close to what I'd like, so I'll have a go and see if I can't manage to fix the legend as well. I'm now wondering if it may be a better idea to add asterisks above the points which have <20 seeds, instead of trying to have them filled/unfilled? Do you think that would be doable?

Comment: Great idea. I have edited my post to include asterisks.